# Autoboxing - Difference between these two lines?

Tags: java, autoboxing

I would like to know the difference between these two:

```
Integer I = 30;  // is it autoboxing?

Integer I = new Integer(30);  // I know it is autoboxing
```

Comment: Case 1: Yes. Case 2: No, its a regular object creation via `new` keyword.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a difference. The first will be treated as

```
Integer I = Integer.valueOf(30);  // autoboxing
```

which will use an `Integer` object already stored in an internal cache (this is true when autoboxing values in the range -127 to 128 inclusive). The second will explicitly create a *new* `Integer` object.

You can see this for yourself:

```
Integer I1 = 30;
Integer I2 = 30;

System.out.println(I1 == I2);
```

```
true
```

vs

```
Integer I1 = new Integer(30);
Integer I2 = new Integer(30);

System.out.println(I1 == I2);
```

```
false
```

In general don't compare `Integer` objects with `==` since that tests for reference equality. I was using it here to test if `I1` and `I2` refer to the same instance. In the first snippet, they do because the `Integer` corresponding to the `int` `30` already exists in a cache, and this instance is used and assigned to both `I1` and `I2`. In the second snippet, they do not since we are creating two independent objects via `new`.

By the way there is no autoboxing involved in the second case, you're just creating a simple new object. There is autoboxing in the first case because an `int` is being implicitly converted to an `Integer`.

You can actually see the effects of autoboxing by viewing the compiled bytecode with `javap -c MyClass`.

Answer (score 2):

In the first line you write

```
Integer I = 30;
```

At the first look you assign an integer (all number literals without an explicit type postfix are considered to be integers) to an object, you think the compiler should complain about incompatible types. But it does not, then this is where the magic happens -> `auto boxing`! The compiler automatically boxes the integer `30` into the object `I`, i.e. it creates an Object which hold the integer value `30` and assigns this to your reference.

In the line

```
Integer I = new Integer(30);
```

You explicitly use the `new` to create an object. So you don't leave the compiler any chance to do anything. Actually, what made so sure that this is `auto boxing`??

Besides of that, the jvm caches a range of values for constants to minimize the memory used for those constants an thus increase performance. To make use of this feature you should get instances of such object using the `valueOf()` method. In that case for same integer value one unique object is returned. If you create it using `new` then for the same constant you'll get a different object each time.